# HTML5 tags are not working in RTF field for TRidion 2011

Tags: html, tridion, tridion-2011

I came across with an issue where RTF field in TRidion 2011 is removing HTML5 tags while saving component.

Issue:
**Source snippet**

```
<div>
     <a class="arrow button" data-role="button" data-inline="true" href="www.google.com">Information</a>
</div>
```

**Tridion is saving above snippet**

```
<div>
     <a class="arrow button" href="www.google.com">Information</a>
</div>
```

In short Tridion is removing HTML5 attribute while saving the component.

Please give some hint to resolve above issue.

Answer (score 11):

For this you can extend the RTF field  to allow HTML5 tags for this you have to specify these tags in a file TcmXhtml.Config at the path

[Tridion]\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\TcmXhtml .

Comment: Hi Ram,Thank you for the post. However by applying above solution I came across with an issue while Tridion fire update query for component in db for all the Tridion component. Any idea how to solved this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Tridion uses XHTML to store rich text fields. Since the attributes you specified are not valid XHTML, Tridion removed them.

You can modify the list of attributes and elements allowed in the Rich Text Area (see Ram's answer) but keep in mind that you are now allowing these attributes to be used in all Rich Text Fields, and you have to consider the impact of this change to your whole environment. If you're doing this as a quick work-around a design limitation (which is what it sounds like) remember that EDITORS will have to do the same. Structure data shouldn't necessarily be in a RTF, and perhaps certain elements of your output should be handled by a template and not by an editor.

Comment: +1, there are plenty of [ways to give content editors a way to specify some functionality without having them add (HTML 5) attributes](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/rich-text-format-area-css-classes-vs-custom-xml-nodes). Consider CSS classes, "merge fields," component links, or a GUI extension in addition to whatever format you choose to store such "inline buttons."

Answer (score 4):

In the \Tridion\web\WebUI\Core\Controls\FormatArea\TcmXhtml\TcmXHTML.config file, update the tag "drop-proprietary-attributes" to be "false":

From: drop-proprietary-attributes: true
To: drop-proprietary-attributes: false

Restart the COM+ and clear the browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question, take a look at the following entry in our Knowledge Base:
[http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/?ArticleId=4065&source=Article&c=12&cid=19#tab:homeTab:crumb:7:artId:4504](http://tridion.kb.sdl.com/kb/?ArticleId=4065&source=Article&c=12&cid=19#tab%3ahomeTab%3acrumb:7%3aartId:4504)

Additionally, you can add other HTML 5 tags in the configuration file mentioned in the article above.
For example, if you wanted to stop the following tags from being removed, add:

**new-blocklevel-tags:** article aside canvas details figcaption figure footer header hgroup nav output progress section video
**new-inline-tags:** audio datalist mark meter summary time
**new-empty-tags:** command source track